# Given three special coins, what is the probability of the next coin toss also resulting in heads?

Tags: probability

Can anybody help me with this problem?

"Having $3$ coins: one with two heads, one with two tails, and one with one head and one tail. If the first coin toss results in heads, what is the probability of the next coin toss also resulting in heads?"

My idea was to divide the situation in two cases. Let $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$ be the coin with two heads, two tails and one head/one tail, respectively.

In the first case, I assume that $c_1$ was tossed, then the probability of getting another head is $0.5 * 0 + 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25$.

In the second case, I assume that $c_3$ was tossed, then the probability of getting another head is $0.5 * 0 + 0.5 * 1 = 0.5$.
I thought of summing the two probabilities, which gives me a $0.75$ of chance. But it seems to high for me.

It's been sometime since I studied probability, so I feel I lack the fundamentals.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to solve or approach the problem?

Comment: To start: You choose randomly the head/tail coin. What is the prob. that the coin shows head? What is the prob. for both events?

Comment: You have asked enough questions here to know that to get help you should show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Are you assuming an equal probability of choosing any of the $3$ coins?

Comment: I'm sorry, guys, it's been a while I don't use this forum. I'll edit the post with the ideas I came up with.

Comment: Initially, the HH and HT coins are equally likely to be the first coin tossed.  However, if the HH coin is selected, then the probability of getting Heads is 1.0.  Alternatively, if the HT coin is selected, then **what  is  the probability of the HT coin then showing heads** ?  Then, what does Bayes Theorem say is the relatively probability that the HH coin rather than the HT coin was the coin tossed?  This preliminary question **must be answered**, before the problem can be attacked.

Comment: Let $H_j$ be the event that the $j^{\text{th}}$ is heads, and let $C_j$ be the event that you picked the $j^{\text{th}}$ coin. Can you compute $\mathbb{P}(H_2|H_1)$? You'll need to find $\mathbb{P}(C_j|H_1)$ for $j=1,2,3$

Comment: When you say "the probability of the next coin.." I presume the "next" coin is different from the first coin ? Pl. clarify, I am holding my answe in abetance until thr clarification is received.

Comment: @trueblueanil I interpret the question differently.  The posted problem specifies "*next coin toss*", rather than (merely) "*next coin*".  I surmise, based on my speculation of the problem composer's intent, and based also on the phrase "next coin toss" that the same coin is to be used for the first and second coin toss.  That is, it seems to me that if the second coin toss *might* involve a different coin than the first coin toss, then the fact that the first coin toss showed heads becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @user2661923: Re your last sentence, see Daniel Cunha answer, and comment that if same coin is tossed, the TT coin becomes irrelevant. Anyway, with OP remaining stoically silent, I am leaving this question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y\in\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$ be the identity of the first coin tossed.   Let $H_1$ be the event of seeing a head on the first toss.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=c_1\mid H_1)&=2/3&&\text{Double Header}\\\mathsf P(Y=c_2\mid H_1)&=0 &&\text{Double Tailer}\\ \mathsf P(Y=c_3\mid H_1)&= 1/3&&\text{Single Header}\end{align}$$

**Reason:** Each from the six faces on the coins has an equal probability of being *the one you see* on *the first toss*, and *two from the three* heads are on the double header.   So the probability that the head you see is *the one on the single header* is $1/3$, while the probability that the head you see is *one from the two* on the double header is $2/3$ .

Alternatively, use Bayes' Rule: $$\mathsf P(Y=c_1\mid H_1)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y=c_1)\mathsf P(H_1\mid Y=c_1)}{\mathsf P(Y=c_3)\mathsf P(H_1\mid Y=c_3)+\mathsf P(Y=c_1)\mathsf P(H_1\mid Y=c_1)}\\\mathsf P(Y=c_3\mid H_1)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y=c_3)\mathsf P(H_1\mid Y=c_3)}{\mathsf P(Y=c_3)\mathsf P(H_1\mid Y=c_3)+\mathsf P(Y=c_1)\mathsf P(H_1\mid Y=c_1)}$$

---

Now define $X$ and $H_2$ likewise for the second toss and use the Law of Total Probability.

$$\phantom{\begin{align}\mathsf P(H_2\mid H_1)&={{~~~~\mathsf P(H_2\mid X=c_3)\mathsf P(X=c_3\mid Y=c_1)\mathsf P(Y=c_1\mid H_1)}+{\mathsf P(H_2\mid X=c_1)\mathsf P(X=c_1\mid Y=c_3)\mathsf P(Y=c_3\mid H_1)}}\\&= \tfrac 12\tfrac 12\tfrac 23+\tfrac 22\tfrac 12\tfrac 13\\&=\tfrac 13\end{align}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am considering the problem in which each coin can be tossed only once, we never know which coin has been tossed, we can see only the outcome.

---

Let $C_h$ denote heads from the regular coin; $C_t$ denote tails from the regular coin; $H_h$ denote heads from the heads-heads coin; and $T_t$ denote tails from the tails-tails coin.

We have $3\times 2\times 1 = 6$ different ways to order the three coins, and $2$ different outcomes for each ordering (which depend on the result of the regular coin), so there are $6\times2= 12$ possible outcomes (all with a $1/12$ chance of happening):

- $C_h - H_h - T_t$ (heads-heads-tails)
- $C_h - T_t - H_h$ (heads-tails-heads)
- $C_t - H_h - T_t$ (tails-heads-tails)
- $C_t - T_t - H_h$ (tails-tails-heads)
- $H_h - C_h - T_t$ (heads-heads-tails)
- $H_h - C_t - T_t$ (heads-tails-tails)
- $H_h - T_t - C_h$ (heads-tails-heads)
- $H_h - T_t - C_t$ (heads-tails-tails)
- $T_t - C_h - H_h$ (tails-heads-heads)
- $T_t - C_t - H_h$ (tails-tails-heads)
- $T_t - H_h - C_h$ (tails-heads-heads)
- $T_t - H_h - C_t$ (tails-heads-tails)

---

If the first toss resulted in heads, we exclude half of the possibilities:

- $C_h - H_h - T_t$ (heads-heads-tails)
- $C_h - T_t - H_h$ (heads-tails-heads)
- $H_h - C_h - T_t$ (heads-heads-tails)
- $H_h - C_t - T_t$ (heads-tails-tails)
- $H_h - T_t - C_h$ (heads-tails-heads)
- $H_h - T_t - C_t$ (heads-tails-tails)

It can be seen that the chance of the outcome heads-heads for the two first tosses is now $2/6 = 1/3 = \boxed{33.333...\%}$

---

A less direct approach is to see that the chance of the first toss corresponding to $C_h$ is $2/6=1/3$, while the chance of it corresponding to $H_h$ is $4/6=2/3$.

If this first heads comes from $C_h$, the chance of the next coin toss also resulting in heads is $1/2$.

If this first heads comes from $H_h$, the chance of the next coin toss also resulting in heads is $1/4$.

Therefore, the probability should be: $\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3}\times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{3} = \boxed{33.333...\%}$

---

It can also be worked out through [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

The probability of getting heads in the first toss is the chance of getting $H_h$ ($1/3$) added to the chance of getting $C_h$ ($1/3 \times 1/2 = 1/6$), which results in $P(H) = 1/2$.

The probability of getting two heads in a row is the chance of getting $H_h$ and then $C_h$ ($1/3 \times [1/2 \times 1/2] = 1/12$) added to the chance of getting $C_h$ and then $H_h$ ($[1/3 \times 1/2] \times 1/2 = 1/12$), which results in $P(HH) = 1/6$.

Thus, the chance of getting two heads in a row, knowing that the first toss resulted in heads is:

$$P(HH|H) = \frac{P(HH)}{P(H)} = \frac{1/6}{1/2} = \frac{1}{3} = \boxed{33.333...\%}$$

Comment: This is not correct.  The probability that you selected the "normal" coin is $\frac 13$, so the probability that your second toss results in a tails is half of that, or $\frac 16$.  I believe you're assuming that a different coin is selected after the first coin is flipped.  That's not how I understand the problem.

Comment: I am sorry Robert, but I think your answer ($5/6$) is wrong. Note that, after the first heads, the chance of the second toss being tails should be higher than $50\%$, since the tails-tails coin still have to be tossed.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, in your version, the same coin is tossed $3$ times? I am assuming that all three coins will be tossed once, but we don't know which is which, we can see only the outcome.

Comment: Graham solved the same problem as you. If the same coin will be tossed twice, and If each face of the three coins has the same probability, the chance of the first toss corresponding to the heads-heads coin is twice the chance of it corresponding to the regular coin. So we have $2/3 \times 1 + 1/3 \times 1/2 = 5/6$ indeed.

Comment: I think this version is a little bit weird, because the existence of the tails-tails coin becomes completely irrelevant...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you flip the same coin twice.  If that's not the case, the first toss is irrelevant and the answer is $\dfrac 12$.

I'm also assuming that *a priori* each coin is equally likely to have been selected.

Let the sides of the coin be distinguishable.  Then there are $12$ equally likely sequences from $2$ coin flips, $4$ sequences from each coin.

All $4$ of the sequences from the two-headed coin will give you a heads on the first toss.  If you chose the "normal" coin, $2$ of the sequences will give you a heads on the first toss.  The remaining $6$ sequences start with a tail, and therefore can be ruled out.  Thus, you may be in any of $6$ equally likely sequences.

Of those $6$ equally likely sequences, only $1$ results in a tail on the second toss.  The other $5$ will result in a heads on the second toss.  Therefore, the probability of a heads on the second toss is $\dfrac 56$.

Comment: Your comment "If that's not the case, the first toss is irrelevant and the answer is $\frac12$." How $\frac12$ ?  Also, if the same coin is tossed, the TT coin is irrelevant !

Comment: @trueblueanil I'm assuming that the alternative problem is just that you flip a coin and then, with replacement, flip a coin again.  If the alternative problem is that you flip a coin without replacement, the probability of a second heads is $\frac 13$.